# How can I call a Web Service from Xamarin Studio?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, web-services, xamarin

I have created a  web service which works fine and i have also added the webservice to my android app project in xamarin studio but i dont know how i can call my web service to work on my android app. I want to insert data into the remote database from my android app.

here is my webservice code

```
[WebMethod]
public string insertData(string title, string coment)
{
    string Message;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Header (title, coment) 
                    VALUES (@title, @coment)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = title;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@coment", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = coment;

    con.Open();
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (result == 1)
    {
        Message = " Details inserted successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        Message =" Details not inserted successfully";
    }
    con.Close();
    return Message;
```

}

also here is my android layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgd"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Comment"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />
    <Button
        android:text="Insert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've added the webservice to my project which gives me a reference.cs code but i dont understand how to use it. can you help with how i can make the text filled data to be inserted into my remote database through my webservce. thanks

Comment: It seems the actual question is "How can I call a Web Service from Xamarin Studio?". The rest of the post doesn't seem to be relevant. Have you tried anything? Googling for "Xamarin Web Services" returns [Introduction to Web Services](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services) as the very first result

Comment: use this http://adrianandroid.blogspot.in/2012/05/access-c-net-web-service-in.html